# Improving Performance Of jQuery, Preloading, Animation and How much is too much?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I read all the similar questions, but none seemed to be a good fit to my question so I decided to pose one here.

I have a photo gallery page on a website.  It manages around 100 images.  It works just fine.  However, I am interested in TQM (Total Quality Management) and Kai Zen (Never perfect, so always improve it).  In these regards, I have some issues:

1. How much animation is too much animation on one page?  If there is no lag when the user is using the page, does that mean the animation can remain?
2. How much preloading is too much preloading?  I am using javascript and jQuery to cache images when the page loads.  It only caches a % of them, and the others load as the user navigates.  How much memory should I be concerned about taking over on client side with the images?  Should I preload all at once, or as the user navigates?  Should I change the way the mechanisms work if there is no lag?

Sorry for a lot of questions with no code, but these do pertain to the implementation of this system and will greatly help me with some of my iterations before publication.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answers here might be somewhat subjective.

I would say that as far as animation goes - there are two things which would stop me adding more - one being when it starts looking laggy/choppy if everything is firing at the same time (but think of the user - you may have a high end PC with a modern, hardware accelerated browser, but they may not).

Before that happens however, I would be looking at the page and just seeing how annoying I find it - there is such thing as too much and with animation, like many things, often you will find that less is more.

For the second question - cache where its sensible.  Don't worry about memory as the client will handle that, but worry about page load speed.  If your page isn't loaded and ready to use within a reasonable amount of time (a few seconds), consider preloading less and doing more 'on demand' as user experience is key here.  An slow website is an unread website.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Codecraft.  There isn't much animation, the menu system animates when it is opened, there is a small ticking clock, and when the albums are shuffled there is an animation of the album covers.

Comment: As for the preloading, it preloads really quickly, but the ondemand stuff sometimes shows the loading of the image on the screen.  Does that mean I should preload more at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

It really quite depend on your target platform and browser...

1. For jQuery animation, animation duration/iteration and property involved will be another factor other than the number of animation. I will say :

   - jQuery animation is ok for desktop for a fews of them, unless not much JS code occupying the JS thread - check the CPU usage. (short, non-looping, simple animation will not push the CPU too hard)
   - jQuery animation is **not okay** for mobile platform, you should use CSS3 animation insteads
2. Avoid loading/preloading too many images at once as network connection using CPU resources and image preloading will occupy certain amount of RAM. 
   (depend on how big of your image and your user memory - unless this is very old machine or mobile device, or this it is big image e.g.2048x1024, most modern desktop will be okay). 
   preload on page by page basis will be a reasonable approach. My suggestion is less than 10, especially you have other ajax request and you may not have rocket fast server, so your loading will be still reasonable.

Comment: The jQuery animation actually works on my iPhone and android :)  What are CSS3 animations?

Comment: I am only preloading images of 1000x700 so that isn't so hard on the user.  I also only preload around 7 images at the start and allow the others to load as they navigate. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @TravisJ 1. certain type of jQuery animation will slow down your phone. they works, but not as smooth as desktop does. 2. 1000x700 x 7 will be okay for beginning, but will user have the ability to keep on loading on same page? this may have problem when there is over 60 on the page for iphone. (or even 30, depend on the ram and connection status)

Comment: For CSS animation, especially for iPhone, check http://www.webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/

Comment: Have to give a lot of credit to jQuery developers as the animation actually works better on an iPhone than on a mac safari lol.  The user will be lazy loading images as they navigate the same page.  They never load more than an additional 8 images at once and the mobile devices seem to be happy with that, although all users see the loading of some of the images (i may try to implement a loading graphic while the images are loading, it takes only <2s on a 3G connection)

Comment: I am fond of the power of css3, but I find that I do not implement the new features because a majority of users are still on some version of IE, and even IE8 does not support ccs3 animation or opacity :(

Comment: i see. Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: 1.4.4 which is bundled with ASP.NET MVC3